# Syntax tree help?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I have one sentence that is an optional practice question for my syntax class that I just cannot figure out. It's ambiguous as far as where the PP falls but I hope someone can help anyways by giving at least one possibility. The sentence is:

The boy will bring my mother Bill's most recent book about global warming when he can.

Please help if you can! It would be great just to look at someone's interpretation to help me figure out the logic behind it. The trees give me a headache, I'm trying to make sense of them :)

Comment: But "Bill" is ordinarily a *man*'s name.

Comment: Hi ncrash and welcome to Linguistics SE! Check the help centre for off topic questions. (For off-topic headaches, head to chat)

Comment: Say it aloud. Which has more stress, "mother" or "Bill"? Look up English nuclear stress to find out where in an English phrase you'd expect to find the most stress.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VqFpS

Comment: There are **two** PPs in your sentence: "about global warming" and " when he can". Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the off-topic aspect of tree-construction, and modifying the example to "The boy will bring my mother Lee's most recent book about global warming when he can" (where you can't rely on gender-to-name correlations), it's necessary to identify two distinct meanings for this, one where the mother's name is Lee, and the other where some other person named Lee has a book. If you can't identify those meanings, that's a problem. If you can, then the question reduces to understanding how to represent an appositive, and how to represent a possessive.

Comment: In the *dative* interpretation, there is an elided preposition "to" before "my mother".